# Accessing an Outer Class's Members from an Inner Class

Tags: apex, class

```
public class Foo {
    public foo() { }
}
public class Outer {
    public Foo foo {get; set;}
    public class Inner {
        public Inner() {
            system.debug(foo);
        }
    }
    public Inner inner {get; set;}
    public Outer() {
        foo = new Foo();
        inner = new Inner();
    }   
}
```

That code would result in the following error:

```
Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: foo at line ....
```

How can my inner class access its outer class's members?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to pass an instance of the Outer class to the Inner class constructor and keep it in a member.

```
public class Foo {
    public foo() { }
}
public class Outer {
    public Foo foo {get; set;}
    public class Inner {
        private Outer o;
        public Inner(Outer out) {
            o = out;
            system.debug(o.foo);
        }
    }
    public Inner inner {get; set;}
    public Outer() {
        foo = new Foo();
        inner = new Inner(this);
    }   
}
```

Alternatively, you could make `foo` static and reference it with `Outer.foo`.

Comment: This is what I have been doing in all other circumstances where this has come up, but a class like Outer (or Foo) will be passed by value and not by reference. In this case, my Outer (and Foo) is a gigantic class which I don't want to copy 50 times. Let me give the static a try..

Comment: Passing `this` from outer to inner is your best bet. In Java you can leverage the implicit pointer that exists between the inner and outer class instances with syntax from within the `Inner` instance like `Outer.this.foo` but SFDC has removed access to this implicit pointer. Per the docs on the [differences between Java and Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_java_diffs.htm): "Inner classes can have instance member variables like outer classes, but there is no implicit pointer to an instance of the outer class (using the `this` keyword)."

Comment: @Daniel Ballinger  this is great, I have been doing the same myself. But a question arises, is this the correct way to hard wire classes together? As this will explode the view-state. What alternatives have you used, is there something apart from this the community recommends? Or is depending on VF to build such complex UI is the right approach?

Comment: @ShaikhMohdNadeem I haven't had problems with viewstate with this approach yet. Nor has it been a problem with String serialization. Probably best to test your specific scenario though with either of the objects has a large amount of data. If there is something you don't want in viewstate use the [transient](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.pages.meta/pages/apex_classes_keywords_transient.htm#apex_classes_keywords_transient) keyword.

Comment: Thank you @DanielBallinger! I'll play a little more with transient. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the params through the Inner Class constructor for sure.

Or completely in a different way, it's to use 'extends' and 'super' : 
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_super.htm